# Publish a PDF on a website with MD5 Hash

Tags: hash, md5, pdf

I want to publish PDF documents on my website. I calculated the MD5 Hash of the file before uploading it. I want to provide this hash so that the downloader can check if the file is okay. What is the best way to provide the hash? Should I just write it as text on my site or is there a standard way to do it?

Comment: Do you want to do this as security measure - e.g. to make sure that an attacker hasn't modified the PDF in transit? Or what are you trying to protect against?

Comment: @Anders One could argue that accidental corruption of data is a threat.

Comment: @Anders Primarily the possible data corruption. Secondarily the threats of modifications by an unknown attacker.

Comment: PDFs can be signed digitally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to provide the hash as text (hexadecimal string) over HTTPS. Otherwise you could just offer the download directly over HTTPS and avoid adding the hash. The important point here is the security provided by TLS, without it your hash will be useless security-wise.

You should use a robust hash, such as SHA-256 instead of MD5.

If you are not interested by preventing an attack but just want to ensure the integrity of the downloads, you should put the downloads over HTTPS and forget the hash. This way, everybody will benefit from it, not only the users who know about hashes, and it will be a more seamless experience.